# How to use VBA to close a pop up connection window?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, popup

everyone! I need to close or cancel a pop up window when my connection does not work.

I used WorkBook.RefreshAll to refresh all the queries in my workbook and I need to check if it worked or not.

To do this I put an `if range("a2").value = format(date, dd-mm-yyyy) then goto error` So an alarm starts if the date in range("a2") is not the date of the day.

Unfortunately, sometimes I have problems of connection and I do not see it. So the pop up below breaks my code.

Does anyone know how to disable it or how to close or cancel it?

I've already tried to use `application.alerts = false` and it does not work.

[[image: Picture of the Pop Up]]

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried send an Alt+F4 ?
theoretically, it will close the active window, other option, if the window always appears in the same place, you can try to move cursor to the x button and set a click

'For alt+F4

```
Sub Close()
   SendKeys "%{F4}"   
End Sub
```

'For move cursor check this
https://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/vba-mouse-move-and-mouse-click-macro/

Comment: The challenge is that the window appears only when I have some connection problem. What I want to do is to keep the VBA code running if it appears (like skipping it). If I use 'alt + F4' I'm afraid of closing any workbook window.

Comment: Is there any IF clause I can use to verify if there is any pop up opened? If so, 'Alt+F4' may work.